# Separatists inflicted their biggest casualties yet for any single attack on Tuesday - I can't understand "yet for any single attack"

Tags: grammar, meaning

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/aleksandar-vasovic-rebel-commander-warns-of-attack-2014-5

> Separatists inflicted their biggest casualties **yet for any single attack** on Tuesday when they killed seven Ukrainian soldiers in an ambush in Kramatorsk. There have been increasing signs of professional leadership among the groups, which nonetheless remain a loosely organized force.

I can't make real sense of **yet for any single attack**.

Comment: Parse it as [their biggest casualties yet] [for any single attack]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of casualties was the largest of any individual attack so far.  The phrasing is trying to precisely count individual attacks as opposed to full scale battles. It may make more sense if you break it up into

"...biggest casualties yet..." or "...largest number of casualties so far..."

"...for any single attack..." or "...when counting individual attacks..."

The language is imprecise in this case as "...any single attack..." could be counted in different ways.